# Is there a secret-sharing public-key-encryption-based service?

Tags: encryption, email, public-key-infrastructure, web-service

I need to share some sensitive information with someone else who can only communicate via E-mail.

I don't love the idea of sharing this information freely over email in plain text, so I was considering encrypting it using asymmetrical encryption (It's not a nuclear missile launch code, I just want to prevent someone finding a copy of the email in the 'sent' folder). I don't mind creating my own keys and so on, but this other person might find it difficult.

Is there a trust-worthy service on the internet that makes it easy to share sensitive pieces of information securely with others (via public key encryption or any other secure method)?

Comment: Google "Portal Based Encryption"... there are many secure email portals that offload the key management and solves the issue that you're having.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "trustworthy". There's plenty of systems/services out there. But unless you're generating and controlling access to the keys yourself, you cannot be confident that the system/service itself doesn't have access to your data - then you need to decide how much you trust them to not abuse that access, or to not be hacked such that an attacker can abuse it.

Answer (score 1):

[Citrix ShareFile](http://www.sharefile.com/) is one such service. It is primarily used for transferring large files, but you can encrypt them.

It's not free, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Boxcryptor](https://www.boxcryptor.com/).  I haven't used it personally, but it looks like you can manage and create groups for secure file sharing.  The video on how to do [secure file sharing on their site.](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/boxcryptor)  Which is included in the free version of their software.

I know it isn't a service, but have you looked into using PGP/GPG?

With PGP/GPG you can create a public/private key pair for yourself.  The other party would have to [generate PGP/GPG keys](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/pgp_keys.html) ([Windows Client](http://www.gpg4win.org/)) themselves, and you would exchange them.  Then you can encrypt with your public key and email it securely to the other party.

You could also use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to do secure file transfers, but this wouldn't be email based.

Hope this gives you some options and helps!

Comment: I would personally use PGP, but imagine asking your grandmother to generate a key-pair using a command-line tool (she wouldn't be happy).

I was looking for some kind of service that facilitated key-generation, exchange, encryption, etc. for non-expert users. I'll give Boxcryptor a try :). Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, I would not have suggested PGP for my grandmother either, lol.  TeamViewer essentially does what you want.  It takes care of all public key generation, and exchange between users.  But you do need to exchange a session password to connect to the other's computer.